# Variable size data structure (e.g. packet) in Rust

Tags: rust

I am new to Rust and trying to find the best representation in Rust for a variable size data structure, such as an IP packet. Consider the scenario below:

I have a pointer/reference to the start of a data structure in memory (e.g. `&[u8]`) with a fixed size header (which contains a length field for the data structure in a fixed, known location) and a variable size body/payload. From this pointer, I would like to construct an immutable reference of a Rust struct.

I assume this is packed with no alignment, but I don't know what is the best way to 1) represent this as a Rust struct and 2) obtain the reference from the pointer to a byte array.
I have read other similar issues and documentations on Dynamically Sized Types (DSTs) but they do not seem to offer the whole solution.

Comment: Is simply wrapping the pointer to the slice like what the [`etherparse`](https://docs.rs/etherparse/0.10.1/etherparse/) crate [does](https://docs.rs/etherparse/0.10.1/src/etherparse/internet/ipv4.rs.html#437-439) not sufficient?

Comment: You're likely better off deserializing the structure instead of trying to directly interpret it as a rust struct. Safer that way too.

Comment: @IanS. I am using IP packet as an example for a data structure that is similar. From the ipv4.rs file, it seems that extracting the header information from the header slice is doing bitwise operations and returning the result rather than returning a reference to that to the memory location that I had in mind.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo could you elaborate on how deserializing is done and why it is safer?

Comment: The "wrapper type with accessors" and "reference cast to a Rust struct" approaches will likely result in similar/identical compiled code, but the former is substantially safer.

Comment: @Mike Any time you interact with this type you will likely need a sized value, so there really isn't a whole lot of benefit to DSTs unless you're doing something _really_ esoteric. Having a wrapper around `&[u8]` with accessors is one way to do it. You could also have the type own the allocation by using `Vec<u8>` instead.

Comment: @cdhowie that does make a lot of sense. How would one of those accessors look like (e.g. type of function, return reference/value, etc.)?

Comment: @Mike See the second link in Ian S.'s comment.

Comment: @cdhowie that made a lot more sense now. Thanks!